# Runtime exceptions in Java 8 function

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I'm using Java 8 Functions and converters and have the following:

**Main class**

```
public final class MainClass {
    public MainClass(
            final Function<InputModel, OutputModel> businessLogic,
            final Converter<Input, InputModel> inputConverter,
            final Converter<OutputModel, Output> outputConverter) {
        this.businessLogic = requireNonNull(businessLogic, "businessLogic is null.");
        this.inputConverter = requireNonNull(inputConverter, "inputConverter is null.");
        this.outputConverter = requireNonNull(outputConverter, "outputConverter is null.");
    }

    /**
     * Request Handler.
     */
    public Output handleRequest(final Input input) {
        requireNonNull(input, "input is null.");

        log.info("input request: {}", input);

        try {
            return inputConverter
                    .andThen(businessLogic)
                    .andThen(outputConverter)
                    .apply(input);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new InternalServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit test**

```
public final class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private Function<InputModel, OutputModel> mockedBusinessLogic;

    @Mock
    private Converter<Input, InputModel> mockedInputConverter;

    @Mock
    private Converter<OutputModel, Output> mockedOutputConverter;

    private MainClass mainClass = new MainClass(mockedBusinessLogic, mockedInputConverter, mockedOutputConverter);

    @Test
    public void handleRequest_SHOULD_throwException_WHEN_inputConverter_throwsException() {
        final RuntimeException inputConverterException = new NullPointerException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);

        // what should I mock here? apply or convert.. apply for `Converter` seems to be deprecated.
        when(mockedInputConverter.convert(input))
                .thenThrow(inputConverterException);

        final Exception exception = assertThrows(
                InternalServiceException.class,
                () -> mainClass.handleRequest(input)
        );

        assertThat(exception.getMessage(), is(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
        assertThat(exception.getCause(), is(inputConverterException));
    }
}
```

The above assertions fail.
I expect that if the `inputConverter` throws an exception, the catch block in **handleRequest** would wrap it to `InternalServiceException`, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Any help?
How do I actually write unit tests for `handleRequest` method? I want to test the behavior when either of `inputConveter`, `businessLogic` or `outputConveter` throws exception.

Comment: Why do you think there should be an exception?

Comment: inputConverter, businessLogic and outputConverter  are just functions so they can throw any exception. But when they are chained using `andThen`, and then wrapped in try/catch block, shouldn't the exception be caught in the catch block?

Comment: I assume the author knows it's throwing an exception.  Are you sure its the lambda that is the issue and not your logging?  Have you done throw new exception(foo) and ensured it really is logging?  Are you sure the other functions don't have try catches inside themselves that are eating the exception, or finally statements that have return statements in them?

Comment: An InternalServiceException is not a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve].

Comment: updated the question again. My apologies for not being clear in my first attempt.

Comment: What is `Converter`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't this line: `when(inputConverter.convert(input)).thenThrow(inputConverterException);` use the mock? Like `when(mockedInputConverter.convert(input)).thenThrow(inputConverterException);`

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is a mock. When you call `andThen` on your mocked inputConverter, then either `null` or a new mock instance is returned (depending on configuration). Each `andThen` will return a new instance with the chained converters (at least that is what I assume)

Make sure you mock all required methods, or better, use real objects instantiated from real classes.

Setting breakpoints and then debugging should help you find the issue. If you set in your try-block, and then single-step through the code, you will see that the way mocks are used in your code will not work. You could also save each result of `andThen` in a variable and then check in the debugger what type each has. I'm pretty sure it will either be `null` or "Mock for class X".